# Missing SCSS option in “which stylesheet format would you like to use (use arrow keys) ” in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

When I try to run this in my terminal, somehow the option for the SCSS is missing. How can I get the option for the SCSS during generate a new project for AngularJs 7?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMvw7.png)

Comment: What happens if you press the down arrow a couple of times? Also please note that all of that is *text*, please don't post screenshots except where absolutely necessary.

Comment: I tried pressing down arrow for few times. But no luck here.

Comment: you can use arrow key to come down and hit space to select SASS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SCSS is an extension for [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) files, so you should choose Sass and you'll be good to go.

Comment: If Sass is good to go, why there is an option for Scss (I was following this [video from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wtnKulcquA) to learn Angular )? isn't it redundant in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I believe when you specify the "Sass" option, the CLI will create .scss for your generated components.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Angular-cli to generate .scss files for your components by default. 
Please add the folowwing schematics in angular.json.

```
    "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
                "styleext": "scss"
            }
        }
```

The Hierarcy of addition in Angular.json SHOULD be. 
please change styles.css to styles.scss too.

```
{
"projects": {
    "projectName": {
        "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
                "styleext": "scss"
            }
        },
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "options": {
                    "styles": [
                        "src/styles.scss",
                        "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
                    ]
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.